# Set up proper URLs for live and admin sites on IIS

Tags: iis, kentico

I have developed a new website using a CMS named Kentico.
After being published on my web server named web3, it consists of 2 folders: a folder for the live site (named live) and one server for the admin site (named admin).
My folder structure looks like:

[image]

For the time being, my IIS installation looks like:

[image]

So i have created an application for the live site pointing to the live folder and an application for the admin site pointing to the admin folder in the Default Web Site of IIS.
Therefore, the URLs to access the websites are http://web3.domain.org/Live and http://web3.domain.org/Admin.
It works fine but I want to access the live site at http://web3.domain.org/ and the admin site as it is now: http://web3.domain.org/Admin.

One solution I found was to create a new website in IIS pointing to the live folder and add a new application inside it pointing to the admin folder:

[image]

It works fine, the live site is accessible at http://web3.domain.org/ and the admin site at http://web3.domain.org/Admin.
However, I am not sure if it is the best option as the admin site is now dependent of the live site. If the live site is down, I won't have access to the admin site while they are technically independent (2 distinct folders).

I also tried to keep using the Default web site with some rewrite rules in a web.config under wwwrooot like :

```
<rules>
               <rule name="Root_URL_Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Live/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
```

but it didn't work.
Your help would be welcome.

Comment: What do you mean the rule did not work? Have you tried to use failed request tracing to check why the rule not work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating two separate IIS sites. One for the admin app (e.g. admin.something.com) and second IIS site for the live app (something.com). Or, if you want to have both apps on the same domain name and the admin app in a subfolder, then you need to use one IIS site - this will be set to the live app and then create a virtual application subfolder and point it to the admin app. So, you will have basically nested admin app - this is not recommended as in some cases IIS can detect two web.config files as nested and it could cause issues. Or, IIS will take the live site's config file as master and ignore the nested one, etc. I would vote for two separate IIS sites.